# Don't repeat yourself while writing unit tests

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, dry

I have multiple singletons in my app that I test like this.

```
SPSchemeParser* (^createUniqueInstance) (void) = ^SPSchemeParser* (void) {
    return [[SPSchemeParser alloc] init];
};

SPSchemeParser* (^getSharedManager) (void) = ^SPSchemeParser* (void) {
    return [SPSchemeParser sharedManager];
};

// Test singleton

it(@"can create a unique instance", ^{
    expect(createUniqueInstance()).toNot.beNil();
});

it(@"can create a shared instance", ^{
    expect(sut).toNot.beNil();
});

it(@"returns always the same shared instance", ^{
    expect(sut).to.equal(getSharedManager());
});

it(@"returns different unique instance", ^{
    expect(createUniqueInstance()).toNot.equal(createUniqueInstance());
});

it(@"returns a unique instance different to the shared instance", ^{
    expect(sut).toNot.equal(createUniqueInstance());
});
```

Now, I don't want to have that snippet copy-pasted in every unit test file that is testing a singleton. So I was wondering if there was a solution of have this code written only once and then used for multiple tests.

Comment: This is like arranging some resources for your test if you follow AAA pattern of writing tests (arrange, act, assert). You should leverage something like a setup that runs before every unit test. Also, a test should not depend on any other test.

Comment: And how/where do I write a setup test that runs before every unit tests that are located in different class?

Comment: If you are writing a test that talks to different class, depending on how you are using it, it may be called as integration test as a unit test should test the members of the same class but it differs in some situations. However, you should check the testing frameworks docs for this setup concept. In .net , we have `[Setup]` attributes to setup any resources that is required to run a test(s).